# Tip screen at startup that can be disabled

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am planning on creating a tip page that pops up with directions on how to use the app, and can be turned off with a checkbox.  I imagine that in order to save the state of the checkbox's selection, I need top store it as a boolean somewhere on the system.  Would this be done in something like a txt file stored locally using IsolatedStorage?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended that you use IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings to persist application wide settings. Have a look at [this article](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-application-settings?mz=27249-windowsphone7) for an introduction and a sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a text file via isolated storage like you say, or alternatively use Isolated Storage Settings for this this purpose. Further detail here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626492(v=VS.95).aspx